# Is there a best practice for storing and retrieving static list in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a application for the first time in node.

My website will include a static list of countries, music genres and so on...

Should I store the data in my database, or should I use a static json file with a list(countries, genre)?

My folder structure looks something like src\lib..scsss..server and so on.

My question ultimately is - Is there a best practice for storing static lists in node  - if a josn file is preferred where should this exist in my folder structure?

Comment: If it is likely that the static data is needed for each request or nearly each request, then it does not make sense to request it every time from the database, so it would be most likely a good idea to cache it in memory. Where you want to store your static data depends on your project. If your static data is also need in your database for some tasks then you will save it there, otherwise you might store it in a `data` directory. So there is no real best practice, because it depends on so many things. And the details are highly opinion based and/or depend on the tools you use.

Comment: Neither countries nor genres will be that static. You will eventually need to change them. Ask yourself how you want that change be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is not gonna change and static, then you should use file system which will have high R/W operation rate compared to communication with DB Server overhead. 
Moreover you can use [filecache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filecache) to cache all your static files. Which will load the files even faster.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is really that "it depends" upon some things you have not specified.

First off, if it is a list of data that does not change while your app is running (or changes very infrequently), then you don't want to load it from some remote source every time you need it.  You will want to load it once and then keep that list in memory for subsequent use.  This will be a lot more efficient for your server.

As to where to store the list in the first place, you have several choices that depend upon who is going to maintain that list and what level of programming skill they might have.

1. If the list of countries will not change often and will be maintained by a Javascript developer, then you can either put the list right into a Javascript literal in your code or in a JSON file in your file system.  If choosing the latter option as a JSON file, it can be in the same directory as your Javascript source files and just loaded directly with `require()` upon startup.
2. If the list of countries will be maintained by someone who is not a Javascript developer, but can be trusted to follow JSON syntax rules, then you can put the list in a JSON file.  Whether you put this file in the same directory as your JS files or in a separate `data` directory really depends more upon how your application is deployed, who has permission to do what, etc...
3. If the list of countries will be maintained by someone who has no idea about programming or syntax rules and should be modifiable completely independently from your code, then you may want to either put it in the database and build some sort of admin interface for modifying it or put it in a plain text file (one country per line) and then parse that file upon app startup.